# Trim a file from the beginning to a certain size in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I'm writing a log file for an iOS app with

```
[logContent writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

and appending to the log file with

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[logContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
```

and everything is working correctly so far. However now I want to limit the log file size to less than 100M, so that each time the log file increases to over 100M, the first part of the file should be trimmed to keep the file size under 100M.

One way I can think of is to read the whole content of the file to an NSString object, trim it to under 100M, and write it back, but obviously the operations of reading 100M content and then writing it back take quite some time and it causes severe performance issues when multiple log writes happens within a short period of time. One work around is to trim to file down to 90M once it grows over 100M, which is a workable solution, but not ideal IMHO. Reading 100M of content and writing back 90M of content still mean that at some point of time it may become laggy due to the log trimming operations.

So I wonder if there are better ways of trimming the beginning of a log file so it may not incur serious performance issues?

Comment: You could read and write asynchronously so it won't block your app performance.

Comment: @koen, so you mean there are no better ways than reading the whole file content and then writing it back trimmed?

Comment: I think you can append to an existing file. Then after writing, check the size and adjust if over 100M.

Comment: @koen, not sure what you mean by "adjust", currently I'm reading the whole content of the file into an NSString and write it back after trimming. I'm wondering it there are better (faster, more efficient) ways of "adjusting if over 100M"?

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Check the [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) for example - disable log rolling by time (frequency = 0), set max log file size to 10MB, max number of log files to 10 and you're done. The oldest 10MB will be trashed once you reach 100MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to consider the file's coding but to use NSString is not efficient.

If you can trim *approximately*, then position the pointer approximately at the right position and seek (byte by byte) until you find a newline and then trim from there.

To trim efficiently once you've find the position, create a buffer and read bytes into it from the position you got earlier, seek to the file beginning and write the buffer there and so on until you've traversed the whole file, then trim the tail.

**EDIT**

This has by now been tested ...

```
// Return YES if file was trimmed
+ ( BOOL ) trimHead:( NSFileHandle     * ) file
         amount:( double             ) pct      // e.g. 0.1 to trim 10%
           size:( unsigned long long ) size     // size if known or 0 to calculate
{
    // If file size is not given, calculate it
    if ( ! size )
    {
        file.seekToEndOfFile;
        size = file.offsetInFile;
    }

    // Calculate where we want to trim
    unsigned long long src = size * pct;

    // Move pointer
    [file seekToFileOffset:src];

    // What we are looking for
    NSData * nl = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Read some data
    NSUInteger len = 100;   // Arbitrary but small as we are just looking for the next nl

    while ( src < size )
    {
        if ( size - src < len )
        {
            len = size - src;
        }

        NSData * data = [file readDataOfLength:len];
        NSRange     r = [data rangeOfData:nl options:0 range:NSMakeRange( 0, data.length )];

        if ( r.location != NSNotFound )
        {
            src += r.location + nl.length;
            break;
        }

        src += data.length;
    }

    if ( src < size )
    {
        // Data destination
        unsigned long long dst = 0;

        // New buffer size - can be a bit larger
        // This is a crucial value, I initially used 10000 but
        // 100000 was faster and I think still easy on resources
        // The larger the file the higher this should be, but
        // even small values should work. Larger should give
        // better performance but use more resources.
        len = 100000;

        // Now shuffle the bytes from here to the start
        while ( src < size )
        {
            [file seekToFileOffset:src];

            if ( size - src < len )
            {
                len = size - src;
            }

            NSData * data = [file readDataOfLength:len];

            [file seekToFileOffset:dst];
            [file writeData:data];

            dst += data.length;
            src += data.length;
        }

        // Done
        [file truncateFileAtOffset:dst];

        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Final comments.

You can combine this with what you do in a single call to firstly append to the file (as you do at present), then check the size (based on position after appending) and if it exceeds some limit call this trim method. Should be really fast based on the few tests I did.

Comment: Ok, very arbitrary test, with a file just over 100M in size. I used my code as is, with the seek to the end to calculate the size. I like my code even more, even though I had to fix it a bit, as zrzka you need to know the number of lines of the file and even if you know that you are not even going to be close to 10% of the file by taking 10% of the lines. My code even calculates the file size and yours should then start by calculating the number of lines.

Comment: The test shows the following. I just ran it twice. Time for your code 0,52s and for mine 0,38s so mine is faster. (Second run more or less the same) Again, mine works out the box while yours need some knowledge of how many lines to cut.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you split it to smaller files? 100mb -> 10 files - 10mb?

One more thing you should keep in mind: don't trim the log file by the size, because you're working with unicode string.

if you trim the first 10mb, the remaining 90mb could be correct or incorrect unicode string, it depends on the last characters in 10mb data trimmed.

Comment: actually, I'm not even sure how to trim the file by exact size, what I'm actually currently doing is to read the whole content into an NSString, get substring from the index at 10% of the whole length, and write the NSString back. I think that takes care of the UTF8 encoding thing right? I'd like to know if there are ways to trim the file to exact size if you know how to do that...

Comment: Yes, if you read whole content of the file as a string then trim it by string’s method, it’ll take care of Unicode issue for you. But it is more time and memory consuming. Why the smaller files approach doesn’t fit for you?

Comment: well, actually the file size is not currently decided yet by the client, so they may want to limit the log file size to 10M or 5M, just not likely over 100M. So my question is not about whether to split the log file into smaller files (the client may decide to limit the log file to 5M in the end AFAIK), but more about how to efficiently trim from the start of the log file. So if using NSString is "more time and memory consuming", what's the "less time and memory consuming" method you suggest?

Comment: Trim the tail of the file could be done without read whole content of the file, but we can’t do the same from the head

Answer (score 0):

### Reinventing the wheel

#### Existing frameworks

It looks like that you're trying to solve something which has been already
solved. There're logging frameworks (like [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)) which allows you to:

- set log files disk quota,
- set max log file size,
- set rotation based on time & size, just time or just size,
- ...

Although, none of them does rotate log file your way.

#### Unified system logging

I don't know what you're storing in the logs, but you should use
[unified system logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging).
If you can afford to target iOS >= 14.0, there's a new API allowing you to
access logs via `OSLogStore`, `OSLogEnumerator`, `OSLogEntry`, ...
[More info here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog).

### Truncate file

#### By number of lines

```c
- (BOOL)removeLinesFromFile:(NSUInteger)lineCount
                      atURL:(NSURL * _Nonnull)url {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                         options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                           error:nil];
    
    if (data == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
        
    NSData *newLine = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    // Iterate till we reach required number of lines
    NSUInteger currentPosition = 0;
    NSUInteger currentLineNumber = 0;
    while (currentLineNumber < lineCount) {
        NSRange range = [data rangeOfData:newLine
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(currentPosition, data.length - currentPosition)];
        
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
            // Not enough lines in the file
            return NO;
        }
        
        currentLineNumber += 1;
        currentPosition = range.location + range.length;
    }
    
    // Create a subdata from data and write them back to the disk
    NSData *subdata = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(currentPosition, data.length - currentPosition)];
    return [subdata writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
}
```

#### By size (approximately)

```c
- (BOOL)trimHeadAtURL:(NSURL * _Nonnull)url
               amount:(CGFloat)amount {
    // A mapped file uses virtual memory techniques to avoid copying pages
    // of the file into memory until they are actually needed.
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                         options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                           error:nil];
    
    if (data == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
        
    NSData *newLine = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger location = data.length * amount;
    NSRange range = [data rangeOfData:newLine
                              options:0
                                range:NSMakeRange(location, data.length - location)];
        
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        // No new line in the search range
        return NO;
    }
    
    // Skip new line
    range.location += range.length;
    
    // Check if there's something left in the file
    if (range.location >= data.length) {
        return NO;
    }
    
    range.length = data.length - range.location;

    NSData *subdata = [data subdataWithRange:range];
    return [subdata writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
}
```

#### Performance

I didn't measure performance of these methods. With performance I mean speed, memory consumption, ... @skaak did some quick tests and his `NSFileHandle` solution is faster. Mine is IMHO more readable, but it's up to you which one you choose.

Comment: you give lots of detail which is good but the solution is not a nice fit. The OP used ```NSFileHandle``` and while you say do not reinvent all three the suggestions will require *lots* of reworking. So stick with ```NSFileHandle``` which is ideal to solve this problem and with the stuff already done by OP will be extremely efficient. The mapped data is better than string but still slow as you will read the whole file into memory, just not all at the same time. Also the way you search for newline makes it much slower than stabbing at the 10% level and then just finding the first newline.

Comment: Feel free to provide a faster and more efficient solution/answer :) OP is using `NSFileHandle` just for appending to a log file.

Comment: It is so nice (and fast) to do this with ```NSFileHandle``` but I hope OP will write the code ... but maybe I'll give it a go since you are asking me so nicely - then you must test your and my code on some 100M file and report results!

Comment: You said faster, you have to proove it :p :D

Comment: If you'll test performance, you have to compare _same_ stuff - I did update my answer and added `trimHeadAtURL:amount:` which is sort of what you're doing, but with mapped `NSData` only.

Comment: Hey I should work ... but testing the new one now as well. I think we need larger files and I think if I increase my buffer size I'll get even better performance but it is now really academic.

Comment: Mine is still best ... times more or less the same but your *new* method is slowest!

Comment: I've upped my buffer to 50k and mine is flying, pushing for 0,3s at the moment while your new method is more than 0,5s for some reason. I tell you, that mapping is wasting memory while I just move the pointer to the spot. Then again, what is the difference between 0,3 and 0,5s ...

Comment: Also pretty arbitrary so to really test I think we need huge files. Maybe these times are due to startup or whatever so we also need a lot of tests but let me stop now thanks was nice. I think we need to delete some of these comments soon ...

Comment: Relax man - 0.5 vs 0.3 is nothing when you compare the readability :) But yes, you're faster. Anyway, I was just interested in what the difference between mapped `NSData` & `NSFileHandle` seeking will be (for the same algorithm). More precisely - if there's any cleverness under the hood, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: Yeah yours is nice and compact but I like my longhanded style ... I think with the same buffer size (on my side, setting my buffer same as what mapped data uses) it will be almost identical.

Comment: I would be really surprised if there is 'cleverness' under the hood. If there was I would loose or we'd be equal, so I sort of betted on the assumption that the mapped data implementation was not that fancy.

Comment: Latest (and last - for now) test, after I upped my buffer to 100k - mine 0,17s your lines 0,46s and your approximate 0,35s. Also, as for the cleverness, I think mine will use less memory. At least I control the buffer size. The mapped data will probably use greedier chunks and use more memory.

Comment: @zrzka, I have tried existing frameworks like CocoaLumberjack however it seems they do not fit my requirements, for example they rotate files but not trimming from the beginning of the file. When I set the number of log files to 1 and a max file size, CocoaLumberjack actually stopped writing to the file with the last log line after the max size is reached thus giving incomplete last log line, and then it cleared the whole file and start again. That's far from usable in my case. I'd love to use an existing log framework if it can trim from the start of the file, but not sure if one exists.

Comment: @zrzka, also I'm not too hot on the file rotating idea as the client want the app to send them one single log file, if I use a rotating solution, I need to concatenate the files into one single file before sending it out, which may be problematic for certain edge cases. Anyway it seems that frameworks like CocoaLumberjack is more fitting to rotating log files on timely basis instead of my client's particular requirements. I'd love not to "reinvent the wheel" if you can point me to some logging framework that can limit file size and trim log file from the start while appending new logs :)

Comment: @hellopeach I have a question - how likely is your app going to send these logs? Is this something user should initiate? Periodically? What's stored in these logs? Isn't just better to concat these log files when they're needed? Isn't this solution (continual trimming) just battery wasting on all these devices? Is the log file size correct requirement? What if these logs will be flooded with messages (like full in 5 minutes) and you'll loose previous logs because of this limit? Will it be useful? I'm just thinking aloud about this, because I doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @zrzka, well, one thing about the log rotation with CocoaLumberjack is that it seems it's buggy with fixed file size, that the last log line of a file may get cut midway when it exceeds the size limit. The log file needs to be sent to the client's corporate email address and possibly over some messaging services (with an existing library provided by the client) so the file size needs to be under a certain fixed limit. That's why I need to make sure to limit the log by file size instead of rotating files on timely basis.

Comment: You mentioned `OSLogStore` but it seems only available for macOS? Is there something equivalent on iOS?